# Delete all columns containing partial value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a VBA code using row 1 header and deleting columns that contain "s2" in their header.  I need a code to search s2 which is a partial search because I have other headers that are labeled xyz s2, abc s2, etc.  so, i want to search anything that contains s2 and delete any columns with this criteria.  anything would help, thx

Comment: Please remember that this is not a code writing website. If you provide what you have tried (i.e. code), people here can than help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cpnsider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Cells(1, i)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(1, v, "s2") > 0 Then r.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your attempt at solving this problem to get help here.

Look into `InStr()` and `.EntireColumn.Delete`